# streamController.add(QueryEvent(DataSnapshot.getInstance(data), string)); error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to flutter and dart. I am trying to make an app that displays data from firebase on a map. I have 3 dart files. The problem is when I edit something in firebase RLdatabase a new file pops up in VScode and highlights this text. I don't know what to do.

```
streamController.add(QueryEvent(DataSnapshot.getInstance(data), string));
```

and debug console shows up this

> ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'streamController': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 15..

main.dart

```
//import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
//import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_map/plugin_api.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';


import 'acasa_small.dart'; // Import the AcasaSmall widget
import 'acasa_large.dart'; // Import the AcasaLarge widget


FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600) {
            // Use AcasaSmall widget for small screens
            return AcasaSmall();
          } else {
            // Use AcasaLarge widget for large screens
            return AcasaLarge();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

acasa_large.dart

```
//import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/plugin_api.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
//import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  
class AcasaLarge extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AcasaLargeState createState() => _AcasaLargeState();
}

class _AcasaLargeState extends State<AcasaLarge> {
  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  List<String> displayText = [];
  String rezultat = '';
  List<Marker> markers = [];
  List<LatLng> markerPositions = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _activare();
  }

  void _activare() {
    database.child('Date').onValue.listen((event) {
      final String desc = event.snapshot.value.toString();
      setState(() {
        rezultat = desc;
        displayText = rezultat.split(",");
      });
    });

    database.child('ACT').onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      setState(() {
        markers.clear();
        markerPositions.clear();
        data.forEach((key, value) {
          final latitude = value['La'] as double;
          final longitude = value['Ln'] as double;
          markerPositions.add(LatLng(latitude, longitude));
          markers.add(
            Marker(
              point: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              builder: (context) => FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ForestSaver"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                child: FlutterMap(
                  options:
                      MapOptions(maxZoom: 18.0, center: LatLng(45.269788, 27.95787)),
                  children: [
                    TileLayer(
                      urlTemplate:
                          'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
                      userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
                    ),
                    MarkerLayer(markers: markers),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: displayText.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  displayText[index],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

acasa_small.dart

```
// import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/plugin_api.dart';
// import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
// import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

class AcasaSmall extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AcasaSmallState createState() => _AcasaSmallState();
}

class _AcasaSmallState extends State<AcasaSmall> {
  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  List<String> displayText = [];
  String rezultat = '';
  List<Marker> markers = [];
  List<LatLng> markerPositions = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _activare();
  }

  void _activare() {
    database.child('Date').onValue.listen((event) {
      final String desc = event.snapshot.value.toString();
      setState(() {
        rezultat = desc;
        displayText = rezultat.split(",");
      });
    });

    database.child('ACT').onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      setState(() {
        markers.clear();
        markerPositions.clear();
        data.forEach((key, value) {
          final latitude = value['La'] as double;
          final longitude = value['Ln'] as double;
          markerPositions.add(LatLng(latitude, longitude));
          markers.add(
            Marker(
              point: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              builder: (context) => FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ForestSaver"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                child: FlutterMap(
                  options:
                      MapOptions(maxZoom: 18.0, center: LatLng(45.269788, 27.95787)),
                  children: [
                    TileLayer(
                      urlTemplate:
                          'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
                      userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
                    ),
                    MarkerLayer(markers: markers),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: displayText.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  displayText[index],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a previous version with only 1 dart file that isnt responsive but works just fine, but since I added the responsive screen files it doesnt work.